# AndroidRuntime(12602): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, runtime-error

I am getting an Error while launching my android application.

com.RareMediaCompany.ChitrguptVersion2.Android.ChitrguptAndroidORMLiteHelper

This class is a part of Library project imported by my application.

[image]

Comment: Have this class in your project? or having this class ectends Application?

Comment: Where is this class (com.RaareMediaCompany.ChitrguptVersi...) located ? Does it in jar library file?

Comment: having you add this project as library in your project??

Comment: can you just give me library name or its link on web that you are using so i get some idea regarding this. may be its content provoder than you have to declare in to manifest so

Comment: @DigveshPatel: This library is not available on web. We are using our own library project and not a jar file.

Comment: if in library you are use content provider than declare in your manifest file please

Comment: No we did not use Content Provider.